Qt On Android: Directory compression
I'm porting a Qt App to Android. One of app critical functions requires that the contents of a directory are compressed. The way I had solved this is by calling tar (external function) because it was a simple cross-platform compressing tool (Windows, Linux and Mac had no issues with this). However, now that I'm on android (possibly iOS) this is no longer an option.
So should I go about compressing a directory? It is important to know that the file will be received by a web server than needs to uncompress it.
Any tips would be appreciated.

More important is to know what decompression capabilities the server has. There are many compression algorithm available, including zlib, which seems supported natively on Android (and is also supported on most OS natively too).

I know. But I wanted to know my options. It seems that qCompress and qUncompress use this. However they are called on byte arrays. How would I call on a Directory? I could figure out how to use zlib in the server (I do have control of it).

@musicamante When you say they are many compression algorithm available are you suggesting to implement them?

No. I'm suggesting to do research about their support on Android, either natively, or through external libraries that you may eventually include. Note that since qCompress() returns a QByteArray, nothing prevents you to call it again with a collection of results (including a QByteArray that is hierarchically structured considering the directory tree), as long as you can do the opposite server-side. Still, you need to consider the possible amount of memory required for the process. I've not enough experience with compression algorithms, but you should do some research on their efficiency.

Most importantly, since Android devices can be quite poor on memory availability or hungry on their usage, you should consider the effectiveness of each algorithm: most importantly, the CPU and memory requirements based on the size/type of data you're going to send. Some algorithms are able to use less memory (depending on how they're implemented), possibly using temporary files, which makes things simpler on one hand, but also difficult on the other (does the device have enough "disk" space?). But if, for instance, you're dealing with already compressed data (eg. images), what's the point?

As said in the beginning, knowing the capabilities of the remote server is a fundamental aspect. If you have full control over it (including being able to process data programmatically), then things may be easier. For instance, you could have a controlled "stream" of data objects that are individually sent as compressed files, which are therefore deflated and finally "recompressed" on the server. Or you could use an alternate algorithm that is less effective in compression but more reliable for the device CPU/memory. There are a lot of ways to achieve all this.
